# Python: Set a list as the value in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of column titles:

```
column_names = ['','column1', 'column2', 'column3']
```

I am trying to create a dictionary to store the max and min values of each column. I have the max/min values but I am having trouble successfully creating the dictionary in a manner like:

```
    {
        'csvfile1' :[{

            "column1": [{
                "max": "154790"
                "min": "134070"
                }],
            "column2": [{
                "max": "148686"
                "min": "125753"
                }],
            "column3": [{
                "max": "80591"
                "min": "40644"
                }]
            }]
    }
```

Here is my script so far:

```
    max_min_data={}
    max_min_data['name'] = defaultdict(column_names[1:])

    for number in range(1,3):

        max_min_data[name][column_names[number]]['max']=max_value
        max_min_data[name][column_names[number]]['min']=min_value
```

This is not working for me, could someone explain why or what I should do to create a structure I described above?

I get the error:

```
KeyError: 'column1'
```

I have previously tried:

```
max_min_data='name'
for number in range(1,3):
   max_min_data[name]=[column_names[number]]
```

But this only gave a key for the 'column3' not all 3 column names

Comment: You should tell us what happens, rather than saying "not working for some reason". I presume you get an error in `defaultdict(column_names[1:])`.

Comment: Why are you putting your `dict`s into single element lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a nested dictionary by implementaing the perl's autovivification feature,

```
class AutoVivification(dict):
    """Implementation of perl's autovivification feature."""
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__(self, item)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[item] = type(self)()
            return value​

# Store data
max_min_data = AutoVivification()
for number in range(1,3):
    max_min_data[name][column_names[number]]['max']=max_value
    max_min_data[name][column_names[number]]['min']=min_value
```

Comment: Thank you but I seem to get the error "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file my_file.py on line 22, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details". Line 22 matchs the return value part of the AutoVivification class

Comment: @Catherine, this error is not caused by my code. Add the line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to your python file.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to append to this dictionary? I have about 4 "names" that I loop through but this seems to rewrite over itself so only the last one remains in the dictionary? AutoVivification does not have an attribute 'append'

Comment: @Catherine, actually, **AutoVivification** is a *nested* dictionary. It does rewrite over itself but is regarded a new key.

Answer (score 0):

as per https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

to create a dictionary key:value you must do the following

dictionary[key] = value

you cannot do dictionary[key1][key2][key3] = value

additionally, i do not see your dictionary declared

dictionary= {}